# How to find the first NaN of an array in F#?

Tags: f#

if I have the following array:

```
let arr = [|1.0; 2.0; 3.0; 4.0; 5.0; nan; nan; nan;|]
```

how can I find the first instance of a *nan*?

I understand I could process the whole array with *mapi*, find the indices, then take the first one. But I need to find an efficient way and stop processing on the first *nan* I encounter.
Are there iterators I can exit on some conditions for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.tryFindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.tryfindindex%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d):

```
let io =  arr |> Array.tryFindIndex System.Double.IsNaN
```